# How to create an entity on creation of another entity and assign it to the first?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a user entity who need to have a default workgroup entity. I would to create this default workgroup at the user creation.

Comment: There are different approaches but the most straight forward is to simply have whatever code creates the user be responsible for adding the default work group.  Since you are using S2 then you could make an UserManager service with a createUser method and just encapsulate this logic in it.  Much easier then fooling around with call backs and such.

Comment: Does the default workgroup already exist in the DB or do you need to create one for every new user?

Comment: @room13, the default workgroup isn't in the database. I need to create for every new user.

Comment: @Cerad, I will try to use my UserManager service. How can I create an entity on create, update et delete event of many entity? Should I need to create a manager for each entity which do the same things but for diffrerent entity?

Comment: Just need one UserManager instance.  You pass it the existing user entity for updates and such.  The approach you take really depends on what all you need for the user object to do.  Starting with a UserManager is an easy way to get going.

Comment: Now you just expanded the scope of the question considerably.  If you plan on using FOSUserBundle then take the time to read through the documentation, get it working and then start adding.  There is a lot going on inside of that bundle and more than likely you will be able to find specific examples for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating the workgroup in the constructor of the user entity?

If i understood your question right, you may just do the following:

```
class User
{
    // annotations left out

    private $firstName;
    ...
    private $workGroup;

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->workGroup = new WorkGroup('default');
   }
}
```

You will have to set the cascade option of the relation between user and workgroup so a unmanaged workgroup will be automaticly persisted. If in some special case you want to assign another workgroup to the user on creation you can just override it before persisting the user object.

```
// user with default workgroup
$user = new User();
$em->persist($user);

// user with special non default workgroup
$specialUser = new User();
$specialUser->setWorkGroup($taskForce);
$em->persist($specialUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Form elements in SF2 can be other forms.  So you can ad an element to the form that is of the type of the form for creating the work group. If the entity is correctly setup it will handle setting every thing on user for you.